# Longest run/island of a number in Python

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I have an array with 0's repeating multiple times but I want to find the longest set of 0s. For example:

```
myArray= [[1,0],[2,0],[3,0][4,0][5,1][6,0][7,0][8,0][9,0][10,0][11,0][12,0][13,1][14,2][15,0][16,0][17,0][18,0][19,1][20,0]]
```

So the Y coordinate has zeros repeating continuously a few times but I need to find the longest run. In this case the longest run is 7 repeated zeros from X coordinate 6 to X coordinate 12. I'd like the program to tell me where the the longest run of zeros is (in this case from X=6 to X=12).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Think of the zeros as the ones we are after. So, we will try to assign them as `True` elements in a boolean array. This could be achieved with `myArray[:,1]==0`. Next up, let's find rising and falling edges of such regions of `0s`. We might have `0s` touching the limits/boundaries of the array, so in those cases, we might miss seeing such rising and falling edges. Thus, to cover those boundary cases, we can pad `False's` or `0's` on either sides and then look for positive and negative differentiation values respectively. The indices corresponding to those rising and falling edges must be the start and stop of `0s` intervals respectively and finally max of those would be the desired output.

We would have two versions to implement such an idea as listed next.

```
def max_interval_len_app1(myArray):
    # Construct a grouped differentiated array where 1s indicate start and -1 
    # as stop indices. Then  store such indices.
    grp_diffs = np.diff(np.hstack(([0],(myArray[:,1]==0).astype(int),[0])))
    grp_start_idx = np.where(grp_diffs==1)[0]
    grp_stop_idx = np.where(grp_diffs==-1)[0]

    if len(grp_start_idx)==0:
        return 0 # No zeros found
    else:    
        # Get 0's interval lens by subtracting start from each correspondin
        # stop indices. Return the max length 
        return (grp_stop_idx - grp_start_idx).max()

def max_interval_len_app2(myArray):
    # Get indices at which rising and falling edges occur.
    idx = np.where(np.diff(np.hstack(([False],myArray[:,1]==0,[False]))))[0]

    if len(idx)==0:
        return 0 # No zeros found
    else:        
        # Since the rising and falling edges happen in pairs we are guaranteed
        # to have an even sized idx . So reshape into Nx2 array and then do 
        # differentiation along the columns, which would be 0s interval lens. 
        # Max of the lengths should be the desired output.
        return np.diff(idx.reshape(-1,2),axis=1).max()
```

Comment: Sorry I don't really understand this, can you elaborate a little? What does np.diff do and np.hstack?

Comment: *"Since the rising and falling edges happen in pairs we are guaranteed to have an even sized idx"* - not if the sequence starts with zeros but ends with non-zeros (or vice versa)

Comment: @ali_m Hence the padding of `False/0` added on either sides to make sure we have those rising and falling edges I think. Adding explanation soon.

Comment: Sorry, didn't spot the padding. This still breaks if there are no non-zeros (you'll get the length of the whole array instead).

Comment: @ali_m Yup, there should be error-checking for that. Adding it soon.

Comment: @NabeelEh Added some explanation. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can start by numbering the consecutive elements in a for loop and then simply get the index of the maximum value.

```
>>> cv, a = [], 0
>>> for x in myArray:
>>>     if x[1] == 0:
>>>         a += 1
>>>     else:
>>>         a = 0
>>>     cv.append(a)
>>> print(a)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1]

>>> mi = cv.index(max(cv))  # finds index of *first* maximum
>>> run = [mi - cv[mi] + 1, mi]
>>> print(run)
[5, 11]
```